# Tsql use of CASE WHEN in WHERE to retrieve data for a single period or all periods

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have created a report that I need to show amounts for a single period of a year or all periods of the same year. 
No problem to retrieve for a single period ...

```
WHERE 
    (TransactionType = 12) 
    AND (FiscalYear = @FiscalYear)
    AND (AccountNumber = 'xxxx') 
    AND (FiscalPeriod = @FiscalPeriod)
```

And no problem for all periods in the year

```
WHERE 
    (TransactionType = 12) 
    AND (FiscalYear = @FiscalYear) 
    AND (AccountNumber = 'xxxx') 
    AND FiscalPeriod between 1 and 14
```

But I would like to create a parameter where the user can enter a single period number to see data for that single month/period but if they leave that parameter blank ('' or IS NULL) then the data for periods 1 - 14 will be returned.

I have tried

```
WHERE 
    (TransactionType = xxx)  
    AND (FiscalYear IN (@FiscalYear)) 
    AND (AccountNumber IN (@AccountNumber)) 
    AND (FiscalPeriod = @FiscalPeriod) 
    OR (TransactionType = xxx)  
    AND (FiscalYear IN (@FiscalYear)) 
    AND (AccountNumber IN (@AccountNumber)) 
    AND (GLTR.FiscalPeriod between 1 and 14)
```

... The above gives me everything ... because of OR

If it is possible to achieve this with A CASE WHEN, I do not have it right ... 
Tried ...

```
WHERE 
    (gltr.TransactionType = 12) 
    AND (gltr.FiscalYear = 2015) 
    AND (coa.AccountNumber = '2000') 
    AND (gltr.FiscalPeriod = CASE WHEN @FiscalPeriod IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @FiscalPeriod END) 
    OR (gltr.FiscalYear = 2015) 
    AND (coa.AccountNumber = '2000') 
    AND (gltr.FiscalPeriod BETWEEN 1 AND 14)
```

Then tried ...

```
WHERE 
    (gltr.TransactionType = 12) 
    AND (gltr.FiscalYear = 2015) 
    AND (coa.AccountNumber = '2000') 
    AND (gltr.FiscalPeriod = CASE WHEN NOT(@FiscalPeriod IS NULL) THEN @FiscalPeriod ELSE BETWEEN 1 and 14)
```

... no go

... and variations of both of the above ... spinning my wheels and know there is a way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: you need parentheses... and/or precedence is getting you

Comment: This is a [catch-all query](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
where TransactionType = xxx
  and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear
  and AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
  and (
        FiscalPeriod = @FiscalPeriod 
    or (@FiscalPeriod is null and FiscalPeriod between 1 and 14)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this is exactly what I need.  Now I can move on ... sure am grateful.